# Trying to Get SQS Message ID with Boto

Tags: boto, amazon-sqs

Looking at the boto docs, I don't see a method of fetching the message identifier when you pull it off of an SQS queue. Can anyone provide some information on how I would get this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Message` instance should have an attribute called `id` which contains the message id.

Comment: I don't see an attribute called ID. When showing all attributes, I see ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp, SenderId, ApproximateReceiveCount, and SentTimestamp.

Comment: To answer in a way to remove confusion from future visitors, for a Message variable called msg, you would call msg.id to retrieve the Message id.